# AWS SES Email Verification RequestId status

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, email-verification

Working on AWS SES Email Verification, after verifying an email i get back a `RequestId` from the response. Im trying to find a way to get an update form that `RequestId` i cant find a endpoint or method that can give me an update on this RequestId status.

```
{
  ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: '1234567890' }
}
```

Here is the docs that im using for the Email Verification https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-email-addresses-procedure.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't track the status of email verification using the `RequestId` received from SES email verification response. Pasting a sample response from SES email verification.

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'abcd-xyz-123', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Wed, 26 May 2021 04:44:03 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': '98768888-1111-qwaq-2222', 'content-length': '248', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}}}
```

To get the status of the email verification, you can try `list_verified_email_addresses` operation. It list out all the verified email addresses. Check whether your required email address is listing in `VerifiedEmailAddresses`. If it is not there then it is not yet verified.

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config
my_config = Config(region_name = 'us-west-2')
ses = boto3.client('ses', config=my_config)
response = ses.list_verified_email_addresses()
print(response)
```

Response:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'xxxxx', 'HTTPHeaders': {'date': 'Wed, 26 May 2021 05:25:00 GMT', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxxxx', 'content-length': '412', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'connection': 'keep-alive'}}, u'VerifiedEmailAddresses': ['example@gmail.com']}
```

Comment: That is what i thought. Thanks.